# ansible. проверка количества символов переменной

Tags: ansible, проверка

У меня есть плейбук в котором часть переменных получается путем ввода с клавиатуры, в частности мне нужно сделать проверку на максимальное кол-во символов для переменной hostnamevar (не более 15 символов).

Пробовал такую конструкцию:

---

```js
vars_prompt:
- name: "hostnamevar"
  prompt: "Enter hostname (less than 15 characters)"
  failed_when: hostnamevar | length > 15
  private: no
```

---

Пробовал такую:

```js
vars_prompt:
    - name: "hostnamevar"
      prompt: "Enter hostname (less than 15 characters)"
      private: no
pre_tasks:
    - assert:
        that:
          - 'hostnamevar|length > 15'
        msg: "'hostnamevar' should be less or equal 15 symbols"
```

---

Пробовал её же оставить как tasks вместо pre_tasks. Абсолютно никакой разницы и никаких ограничений на ввод. Уважаемые, посоветуйте, как же все-таки реализовать такую проверку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый пример ничего не сделает, т.к. у промптов нет `failed_when`.

Второй пример работает правильно, но подозреваю, что вы хотели написать либо:

```
- assert:
    that: hostnamevar|length < 15
```

либо

```
- fail:
  when: hostnamevar|length >= 15
```

В `assert` должно быть условие "как надо", в `fail` должно быть условие "как не надо".